# Python Pandas Counting the Occurrences of a Specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the number of times a certain value appears in one column.

I have made the dataframe with `data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data/DataSet2.csv')`

and now I want to find the number of times something appears in a column. How is this done?

I thought it was the below, where I am looking in the education column and counting the number of time `?` occurs.

The code below shows that I am trying to find the number of times `9th` appears and the error is what I am getting when I run the code

**Code**

```
missing2 = df.education.value_counts()['9th']
print(missing2)
```

**Error**

```
KeyError: '9th'
```

Comment: `df.education.value_counts()['?']` should be correct. What does it give you instead? (show some code and actual output)

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Maybe you need `print df[df.education == '9th'].count()`

Comment: Could be generalized as `(df['Column'].values == 'a').sum()`

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can create `subset` of data with your condition and then use [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) or `len`:

```
print df
  col1 education
0    a       9th
1    b       9th
2    c       8th

print df.education == '9th'
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: education, dtype: bool

print df[df.education == '9th']
  col1 education
0    a       9th
1    b       9th

print df[df.education == '9th'].shape[0]
2
print len(df[df['education'] == '9th'])
2
```

Performance is interesting, the fastest solution is compare numpy array and `sum`:

[image: graph]

**Code**:

```
import perfplot, string
np.random.seed(123)


def shape(df):
    return df[df.education == 'a'].shape[0]

def len_df(df):
    return len(df[df['education'] == 'a'])

def query_count(df):
    return df.query('education == "a"').education.count()

def sum_mask(df):
    return (df.education == 'a').sum()

def sum_mask_numpy(df):
    return (df.education.values == 'a').sum()

def make_df(n):
    L = list(string.ascii_letters)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(L, size=n), columns=['education'])
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[shape, len_df, query_count, sum_mask, sum_mask_numpy],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 25)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False, 
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

Answer (score 37):

Couple of ways using `count` or `sum`

```
In [338]: df
Out[338]:
  col1 education
0    a       9th
1    b       9th
2    c       8th

In [335]: df.loc[df.education == '9th', 'education'].count()
Out[335]: 2

In [336]: (df.education == '9th').sum()
Out[336]: 2

In [337]: df.query('education == "9th"').education.count()
Out[337]: 2
```

Answer (score 26):

An elegant way to count the occurrence of `'?'` or any symbol in any column, is to use built-in function **`isin`** of a dataframe object.

Suppose that we have loaded the 'Automobile' [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/toramky/automobile-dataset) into `df` object.
We do not know which columns contain missing value (`'?'` symbol), so let do:

```
df.isin(['?']).sum(axis=0)
```

`DataFrame.isin(values)` official document says:

> it returns boolean DataFrame showing whether each element in the DataFrame
>   is contained in values

Note that `isin` accepts an *iterable* as input, thus we need to pass a list containing the target symbol to this function. `df.isin(['?'])` will return a boolean dataframe as follows.

```
    symboling   normalized-losses   make    fuel-type   aspiration-ratio ...
0   False       True                False   False       False
1   False       True                False   False       False
2   False       True                False   False       False
3   False       False               False   False       False
4   False       False               False   False       False
5   False       True                False   False       False
...
```

To count the number of occurrence of the target symbol in each column, let's take `sum` over all the rows of the above dataframe by indicating `axis=0`.
The final (truncated) result shows what we expect:

```
symboling             0
normalized-losses    41
...
bore                  4
stroke                4
compression-ratio     0
horsepower            2
peak-rpm              2
city-mpg              0
highway-mpg           0
price                 4
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
(df[education]=='9th').sum()
```

Comment: This could be improved by putting the code in a code block (indent 4 spaces) and with an explanation of what the code is doing.

Comment: This will return a `pd.Series` with boolean value of `True` for when an entry in the column `df['education']` == `'9th'` and `False` otherwise. `sum()` will count the number of `True` values

Answer (score 6):

easy but not efficient:

```
list(df.education).count('9th')
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple example to count occurrences (unique values) in a column in Pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

# URL to .csv file 
data_url = 'https://yoursite.com/Arrests.csv'
# Reading the data 
df = pd.read_csv(data_url, index_col=0)
# pandas count distinct values in column 
df['education'].value_counts()
```

Outputs:

```
Education        47516 
9th              41164 
8th              25510 
7th              25198 
6th              25047                       
...  
3rd                 2 
2nd                 2 
1st                 2 
Name: name, Length: 190, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

for finding a specific value of a column you can use the code below

irrespective of the preference you can use the any of the method you like

```
df.col_name.value_counts().Value_you_are_looking_for
```

take example of the titanic dataset

```
df.Sex.value_counts().male
```

this gives a count of all male on the ship
Although if you want to count a numerical data then you cannot use the above method because value_counts() is used only with series type of data hence fails
So for that you can use the second method example

the second method is

```
#this is an example method of counting on a data frame
df[(df['Survived']==1)&(df['Sex']=='male')].counts()
```

this is not that efficient as value_counts() but surely will help if you want to count values of a data frame
hope this helps

EDIT --
If you wanna look for something with a space in between

you may use

`df.country.count('united states')`
I believe this should solve the problem

Comment: what if the we want to find the count for a entry having spacing, for ex:  United States. I tired  replacing empty space with underscore, it didn't work.

Comment: the first method wont work , but the second method will

Comment: for ex:- df[df['country']=='united states'].counts()

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a more easy solution. Suppose you have the following data frame.

```
DATE        LANG        POSTS
2008-07-01  c#          3
2008-08-01  assembly    8
2008-08-01  javascript  2
2008-08-01  c           85
2008-08-01  python      11
2008-07-01  c#          3
2008-08-01  assembly    8
2008-08-01  javascript  62
2008-08-01  c           85
2008-08-01  python      14
```

you can find the occurrence of LANG item's sum like this

```
df.groupby('LANG').sum()
```

and you will have the sum of each individual language

Comment: Please format this answer.