# How to find number of zeros in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame

```
Date      Open   Close
20190101  23.00  0
20190102  0      0
20190103  19     18
20190104  21     19
```

I first turn all the NaN to zeros, then I am going to change all the zeros to the numbers based on the non zeros using `interpolate(limit_direction='both')`.  Prior to doing this I would like to count how many zeros there are in the whole dataframe to check how much data corruption there is.

I cannot seem to find it. I believe its along the lines of turning them to boolean and counting that way but have been unsuccessful so far.

EDIT:  `(df == 0).sum().sum()` worked perfect thanks

Comment: `(df == 0).sum()` will summarize the number of zeroes in each column. `(df == 0).sum().sum()` will show the total number of zeroes in the whole dataframe

Comment: Do you mean `df[['Open', 'Close']].eq(0).sum().sum()` ?

Comment: `print(np.count_nonzero(df==0))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Counting the Occurrences of a Specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277075/python-pandas-counting-the-occurrences-of-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Pandas DF.

Filtering the column may be useful.

```
df.Open[df.Open==0].count()
```

If you want to count every 0 in the dataframe, you can loop over on the columns.

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {'Date':[20190101 ,20190102 ,20190103  ,20190104  ],
'Open':[23,0,19,21],
'Close':[0,0,18,19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

df.Open[df.Open==0].count()
```

looping over on the Columns

```
num = 0
for i in df.columns:
   num += df[i][df[i]==0].count()
num
```