# Count number of occurences of a particular value in each column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have generated a pandas dataframe using below code where an example sequence column is like '0-0-0-1-0-0-2-0-0-0-0'
I split the sequence string into different columns

```
df = DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'sequence'])
print(df.sequence.str.split("-", expand=True))
```

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

0   0   0   0   1   0   0   2   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   2   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0

If I want to count the number of occurences of 0 in each column, how do I do it?

I tried something like this print `df[df.education == '9th'].count()` based on [Python Pandas Counting the Occurrences of a Specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277075/python-pandas-counting-the-occurrences-of-a-specific-value) but I don't have column names appropriately, and I am not sure how to do it.

Can you please help.

Comment: Do you mean `df.eq(0).sum()`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of `data`. - [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
df.rename(columns={"A": "NewName", "B": "NewName"})
```

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)