# Is there a python function to run a count where a specific variable has a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, count, where-clause

I am able to run a count on the entire dataset easily using

```
import pandas as pd
data['eventcode'].value_counts()
```

which produces counts for all the unique values in the column 'eventcode'. Now I want to run the same count process but only where a different column has value 1. How should I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Counting the Occurrences of a Specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277075/python-pandas-counting-the-occurrences-of-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.loc`:

```
data.loc[data['othercolumn'] == 1,'eventcode'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first filter using the other column and then execute `value_counts()` like such:

```
data[data['othercolumn'] == 1]['eventcode'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this for multiple unique values you can `groupby` + `size` and then select the value you need for the subset from the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(410112)
df = pd.DataFrame({'othercol': np.random.choice(range(3), 100),
                   'eventcode': np.random.choice(list('abc'), 100)})

s = df.groupby(['othercol', 'eventcode']).size()
#othercol  eventcode
#0         a            10
#          b            10
#          c             9
#1         a            17
#          b            15
#          c            10
#2         a            10
#          b            12
#          c             7

# Where `df['othercol'] == 1`
s.loc[1]
#eventcode
#a    17
#b    15
#c    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly iterate through uttering vectors and add to your counter

```
cnt = 0
def set_count(row):
    if row[different_column_name] == 1
        cnt +=1
data['different_column_name'].apply(set_count)
```

Comment: Careful with this code as it can only be executed once or cnt must be reset manually. Also, using apply() is generally less performant than using the pandas built-in methods and functions.