# count values by name in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to count number of values by their name?
I have a pandas data frame:

```
word token 
physical I-Problem 
design I-Problem 
for I-Problem 
XML I-Problem 
databases I-Problem 
which o 
is o 
the o 
process o
```

I need to count how many I-Problem in the token.
I tried `df['token'].count('I-Problem')` but it doesn't work.

expected output :

```
I-Problem : 5
```

or

```
5
```

Comment: Could've used [str.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) instead of just count `df['token'].str.count('I-Problem').sum()` though apparently numpy sum is fastest `(df['token'].values == 'I-Problem').sum()` things may have changed over time though [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35277776/15497888)

Answer (score 2):

Use `value_counts`:

```
>>> df['token'].value_counts()['I-Problem']
5
>>>
```

Or try `tolist`:

```
>>> df['token'].tolist().count('I-Problem')
5
>>>
```